# What is regex for date validation for m/d/yy h:m and mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, datetime

It should allow

```
1/1/17 1:10
10/10/2017 01:10
```

Not allowed variants:

```
1/1/17    1:10
10/10/201701:10
```

what I have

```
let activityDateRegex = /^(((0[13578]|1[02])[\/](0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[\/]((19|[2-9]\‌​d)\d{2})\s(0[0-9]|1[‌​0-2]):(0[0-9]|[1-59]‌​\d)\s(AM|am|PM|pm))|‌​((0[13456789]|1[012]‌​)[\/](0[1-9]|[12]\d|‌​30)[\/]((19|[2-9]\d)‌​\d{2})\s(0[0-9]|1[0-‌​2]):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d‌​)\s(AM|am|PM|pm))|((‌​02)[\/](0[1-9]|1\d|2‌​[0-8])[\/]((19|[2-9]‌​\d)\d{2})\s(0[0-9]|1‌​[0-2]):(0[0-9]|[1-59‌​]\d)\s(AM|am|PM|pm))‌​|((02)[\/](29)[\/]((‌​1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48‌​]|[2468][048]|[13579‌​][26])|((16|[2468][0‌​48]|[3579][26])00))\‌​s(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):(0[‌​0-9]|[1-59]\d)\s(AM|‌​am|PM|pm)))$/;
```

Comment: where is your tried code?

Comment: ...in addition to code, can you _clearly_ show us the matching and non-matching date patterns?

Comment: let activityDateRegex = /^(((0[13578]|1[02])[\/](0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[\/]((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})\s(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d)\s(AM|am|PM|pm))|((0[13456789]|1[012])[\/](0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)[\/]((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})\s(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d)\s(AM|am|PM|pm))|((02)[\/](0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])[\/]((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})\s(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d)\s(AM|am|PM|pm))|((02)[\/](29)[\/]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))\s(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d)\s(AM|am|PM|pm)))$/;

Comment: @Abhijeet a small note. When someone asks you to show your effort, you should add your effort in question and not in comment

Comment: Do you understand what this regex means?

Comment: @Toto this is not duplicate question

Comment: In fact it is. Learn first what your regex does and you will be able to change it to meet your requierement.

Answer (score -1):

This will do the trick `\d\d?\/\d\d?\/(\d\d)?\d\d\s\d\d?:\d\d`

https://regex101.com/r/yqMk1n/1

Comment: thanks Roko C. Buljan, Dennis Koch but it should not accept date more than 31 and monthe more than 12.

Comment: @Abhijeet note that the above makes no difference in `dd/mm/yyyy` and `mm/dd/yyyy`  ;) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

Comment: Dennis, note also that `\d\d?\/` can match `00/` ... if that's a valid date I'm superman!!

Comment: Sorry, I was on my mobile phone and tried to provide a quick solution.  Before I'm reinventing the whell I suggest this regex: https://regex101.com/library/pZ4gG4